# Convert row values to column values with 1 for presence and 0 for absence in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

What I want to do is convert data from this format:

```
ID    Date          CODE
5567  2012-09-02    F17
5567  2012-10-15    F17
5567  2012-11-11    Z49
1245  2010-09-02    Z49
6623  2012-10-15    T65
6623  2012-11-11    Z49
```

To this format:

```
ID    F17  Z49  T65
5567  1    1    0
1245  0    1    0
6623  0    1    1
```

Notice that I do not care about "Date" nor do I care about how many times a specific code is associated with an ID. I only care if a certain ID has a code associated with it 1 or more times. i.e. 1 = yes and 0 = no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from `data.table` here:

```
dcast(dt, ID ~ CODE, fun.aggregate = function(x) 1L, fill = 0L)
     ID F17 T65 Z49
1: 1245   0   0   1
2: 5567   1   0   1
3: 6623   0   1   1
```

**data**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("ID    Date          CODE
5567  2012-09-02    F17
5567  2012-10-15    F17
5567  2012-11-11    Z49
1245  2010-09-02    Z49
6623  2012-10-15    T65
6623  2012-11-11    Z49")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `table` in base R like below

```
+(table(df1[-2])>0)
```

which gives

```
      CODE
ID     F17 T65 Z49
  1245   0   0   1
  5567   1   0   1
  6623   0   1   1
```

Comment: sorry what does the "+" and the values -2,0 refer to? columns?

Comment: @Melderon `+` turns logical values to numeric, `-2` means we exclude the 2nd column from the data frame `df1`, and `0` is for counting the number of occurrence

Comment: Got it thanks. I used markus's suggestion and it worked well. I appreciate you adding yours!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   distinct(ID, CODE) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = CODE, values_from = CODE,
       values_fn = list(CODE = length), values_fill = list(CODE = 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     ID   F17   Z49   T65
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  5567     1     1     0
#2  1245     0     1     0
#3  6623     0     1     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(5567L, 5567L, 5567L, 1245L, 6623L, 6623L
), Date = c("2012-09-02", "2012-10-15", "2012-11-11", "2010-09-02", 
"2012-10-15", "2012-11-11"), CODE = c("F17", "F17", "Z49", "Z49", 
"T65", "Z49")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```